# SQL USE INDEX Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax, syntax-error

I am using this line on my MySQL database:

```
SELECT * FROM `dump` USE INDEX `time_desc` WHERE (`nodeId`=10047 AND `time`<=1377040709 AND `valid`=1) ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I cannot figure out why, but the database is returning the following error:

> [Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'time_desc WHERE `nodeId`=10048 AND
>   `time`<=1377040709 AND `valid`=1 ORDER BY `ti' at line 1]

Any thoughts as to how I can fix this?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html You need to enclose `time_desc` in parens `(time_desc)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parentheses around the index name

```
SELECT * 
FROM `dump` USE INDEX (`time_desc`)
WHERE (`nodeId`=10047 AND `time`<=1377040709 AND `valid`=1) 
ORDER BY `time` DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM `dump` USE INDEX (`time_desc`)    --Use paranthesis here
WHERE (`nodeId`=10047 AND `time`<=1377040709 AND `valid`=1) 
ORDER BY `time` DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Check this for [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html).